# Multiply by a percentage increase in R

Tags: r, percentage, multiplication

How do you multiply a number by a percentage increase in R. E.g.

43424 increasing by 120% would be 43424 * 2 + 43424 * 0.2

I have increases by 200% + 
and decreases in percentage as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple case:

```r
increase    <- 1.20
start_value <- 43424
inc_value   <- start_value * (1 + increase)
```

If you don't want for some reason calculate the percentage, define a value without the `%`-sign

```r
percentage  <- 120
increase    <- percentage/100
start_value <- 43424
inc_value   <- start_value * (1 + increase)
```

If you just have values with `%` you could transform them into numerical values

```r
percentage  <- c("120 %", "-200%")
increase    <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:space:]]*%", "", percentage))/100
start_value <- 43424
inc_value   <- start_value * (1 + increase)
```

The regular expression uses removes all spaces and a following `%`. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks this is great, but what do I do if the start values is different, e.g. startvalue1 is 200 and startvalue2 is 300 but percentagechange1 is 200% and percentagechange2 is -50

Comment: If your startvalues are given by `c(43242, 12345)` and your percentage change is given by `c("120 %", "150%")` then `start_value * (1 + increase)` gives you `43424*2.2` and `12345*2.5` at once.

Comment: @user123231322 And if you are satisfied, feel free to accept the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). :-)